# Code Not working in VS Code but works in OnlineGDB

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, primes

I am practicing about **primeSieve** with **C++** language in **VS Code 1.57.1**.

But the attached code doesn't show output in VS Code while it shows output in online c++ compiler like
https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void primeSieve(){//Genearate array containing prime number
    int number;
    cin>>number;
    int p[1000] = {0}; //1=Prime;0=Non-Prime
    
    //Mark All Odd number prime
    for(int i=3;i<=1000;i+=2){
        p[i]=1;
    }
    //Sieve
    for(int i=3;i<=1000;i+=2){//jumping over odd numbers
        //if current number is not marked(it is prime)
        if(p[i]==1){
            //Mark Multiples as 0
            for(int j=2*i;j<=1000;j=j+i){
                p[j]=0;
            }
        }
    }
    //Special Case
    p[2]=1;
    p[1]=p[0]=0;

    for(int x=0;x<=number;x++){
        if(p[x]!=0){
            cout<<x<<" ";
        }
    }
}
int main(){
    primeSieve();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `p[1000]` and `i<=1000` and `p[i]=1` causes buffer overrun error.

Comment: @S.M. Also for the `j` loop.

Comment: don't use online compilers they are not good

Comment: I think _only_ the `j` loop will actually attempt to write to `p[1000]`, since the other ones start at `3` and increment by `2` each time so `i` will go directly from `999` to `1001`. But for instance in the sieve loop when `i = 5`, eventually `j` is `1000` exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Size of `p[]` is `1000`. Your loop goes up to `1000`. Try removing the `=` in the loops and just keep `i < 1000`.